# Keep old default printer name on new print server

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, migration, printers

I have a task to update all client printer settings during a migration from and old 2003 R2 print server to a new 2008 R2 print server. All clients are Win7 with Powershell 2.0 and I created a script that adds new printers and deletes old printers on the client.

However, it mess up the default printer setting on the client, it seems to be random if it changes the default printer to a randrom printer or if no default printer is set at all.

I was thinking to use the method Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Printer -Filter "Default = $true" and that works, I can see the correct (and old) default printer.

But if I try to set the new default printer to the same name, it fails (or more precisely, it just gets random what happens).

Maybe I am putting the function $printer.SetDefaultPrinter() on the wrong place?

Code:

```
 Param (
    $newPrintServer = "Server2",
    $PrinterLog = "\\LogSVR\PrintMigration$\PrintMigration.csv"
)
<#
    #Header for CSV log file:
    "COMPUTERNAME,USERNAME,PRINTERNAME,RETURNCODE-ERRORMESSAGE,DATETIME,STATUS" | 
        Out-File -FilePath $PrinterLog -Encoding ASCII
#>
Try {
    Write-Verbose ("{0}: Checking for printers mapped to old print server" -f $Env:USERNAME)
    $printers = @(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Printer -Filter "SystemName='\\\\Server1'" -ErrorAction Stop)
    $DefPrinter = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Printer -Filter "Default = $true"

    If ($printers.count -gt 0) {        
        ForEach ($printer in $printers) {
            Write-Verbose ("{0}: Replacing with new print server name: {1}" -f $Printer.Name,$newPrintServer)
            $newPrinter = $printer.Name -replace "Server1",$newPrintServer  
            $returnValue = ([wmiclass]"Win32_Printer").AddPrinterConnection($newPrinter).ReturnValue                
            If ($returnValue -eq 0) {
                "{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}" -f $Env:COMPUTERNAME,
                                             $env:USERNAME,
                                             $newPrinter,
                                             $returnValue,
                                             (Get-Date),
                                             "Added Printer" | Out-File -FilePath $PrinterLog -Append -Encoding ASCII            
                Write-Verbose ("{0}: Removing" -f $printer.name)
                $printer.Delete()
                "{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}" -f $Env:COMPUTERNAME,
                                             $env:USERNAME,
                                             $printer.Name,
                                             $returnValue,
                                             (Get-Date),
                                             "Removed Printer" | Out-File -FilePath $PrinterLog -Append -Encoding ASCII
                         $DefPrinter.SetDefaultPrinter()            

} Else {
                Write-Verbose ("{0} returned error code: {1}" -f $newPrinter,$returnValue) -Verbose
                "{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}" -f $Env:COMPUTERNAME,
                                             $env:USERNAME,
                                             $newPrinter,
                                             $returnValue,
                                             (Get-Date),
                                             "Error Adding Printer" | Out-File -FilePath $PrinterLog -Append -Encoding ASCII
            }
        }
    }
} Catch {
    "{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}" -f $Env:COMPUTERNAME,
                                 $env:USERNAME,
                                 "WMIERROR",
                                 $_.Exception.Message,
                                 (Get-Date),
                                 "Error Querying Printers" | Out-File -FilePath $PrinterLog -Append -Encoding ASCII
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding, but the default printer(defprinter) is also located on server1, right? so you create a link defprinter to printer x. then you delete all printers(including printer x) and you try to make defprinter(which no longer exists) default printer again. That won't work and a random printer will get the default attribute.

1st, you should store the unique printername($printer.name) of the defprinter before the loop starts. then when the loop is done: you search for the newly created printer wmi-object that represents the previous default printer(using the printername you saved pre-loop) and make that default..